# Design of JAW with click on each tooth

Tags: android, xml, android-design-library

I want to create and view as shown in the image for one of my apps to store the information of each tooth run time. So is there any library available to achieve this or any trick to achieve this.  Please help me with your valuable suggestion or thoughts to achieve this kind of view.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could layout that view using ConstraintLayout and [Circular Positioning](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#CircularPositioning).

For example, to layout the following:
[image: Sample Layout]

You can write the following xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tooth1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/center"
        app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="270"
        app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tooth2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/center"
        app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="315"
        app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tooth3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/center"
        app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="0"
        app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tooth4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/center"
        app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="45"
        app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tooth5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/center"
        app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="90"
        app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Instead of using TextViews you could use ImageViews and customize each tooth image.

You should also change the following properties on each tooth:

- `app:layout_constraintCircleAngle` to provide the angle degrees from the center.
- `app:layout_constraintCircleRadius` to provide the distance in dps from the center.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not work in the case of 16 teeth at a time if we try to do so it won't give much clickable area.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify your requirement? I thought you asked how to layout a view and this is a way to do it. The clickable area in the layout you specified would always be really small. Maybe you should re-think it?